# Can we convert .exe file to .apk on Windows?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created calculator using tkinter. It's in .exe I won't to convert it into apk and use it in my mobile.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible. Hoverer you can create Android application in Python using frameworks like this: Kivy or other similar.

Exe is a build target for Windows API - and as far I know it's not possible to just convert it to apk file ( which is a build for Android )

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Create your own application using android studio